# IE failing $.inArray() due to type casting

Tags: php, jquery

This code works fine for firefox & chrome, but the Internet Explorer 10 is failing (always returning -1):

```
if (room.room.isGroupChat == 1 && $.inArray(WCF.User.userID, room.users) == -1) {
    console.log(WCF.User.userID); // returns 297
    console.log(room.users); // returns 297,452,637,483,9,14,71,372 
    console.log($.inArray(WCF.User.userID, room.users)); // returns -1
}
```

`room.users` is passed via AJAX:

```
$users = array();
if ($message->type == CChat::MESSAGE_KICKED) {
    $roomUsers = $room->getUsers();

    foreach ($roomUsers as $user) {
        $users[] = $user->userID;
    }
}
```

But if I type cast `(int) $user->userID` it works fine in IE. 
Is there a chance to get it working in IE without type casting?

Comment: Is `room.users` an array of numbers or strings? What data type is `WCF.User.userID`? If you have to cast the value and it works, then I'm actually surprised it works in Chrome and FF at all. Because `$.inArray` uses strict comparison, so the data type of the value you are searching and the values in the array must be the same.

Comment: I just figured out, that `$user->userID` returns a string. But why is `$.inArray` then working in chrome and firefox if there are different types?